# Shifting a date time index

Tags: python, pandas

Please consider this date time index and its one missing date. It does not have any frequency (irregular time series).

```
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([ '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', None, '2018-01-05'])))
```

**Goal**: shift the date time index elements one **available** AND **business** 
day forward.

**What I have:**

```
index2 = index.shift(1, 'B')
```

or:

```
index2 = index + BDay(1)
```

**Results:**

```
In [156]:index
Out[156]: DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', 'NaT', '2018-01-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [157]:index2
Out[157]: DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-03', '2018-01-04', 'NaT', '2018-01-08'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

**Issue:** `2018-01-04` in `index2` is in fact the next business day after `2018-01-03` but it's not in `index`, meaning that data is not available for that date. So, the code shifted the index one business day forward but not one business AND available day forward.

**Desired results:**

```
In[157]:index2
Out[157]: DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-03', '2018-01-05', 'NaT', 'NaT'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

**Thank you.**

Comment: Your input '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', None, '2018-01-04', and another input ['2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', 'NaT', '2018-01-05'], which one we should use

Comment: Why does your first index show `'2018-01-04'` but your second index show `'2018-01-05'`?

Comment: Please define what is meant by available?

Comment: I would go for custom function adding one business day in a loop and checking if it is available and still lower or equal than last available day.

Comment: @Wen sorry, fixed the inconsistency.

Comment: @Jarad sorry, fixed the inconsistency.

Comment: @BryceRamgovind, sorry for being unclear. By available, I mean existing in the original index (`index`). That is my dataframe's index.

Comment: @Saeed add a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the shift day, I think you are  looking for shift position

```
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([ '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', None, '2018-01-05'])))
Newindex=(index[1:].dropna())
Newindex.append(pd.Index([pd.NaT]*(len(index)-len(Newindex))))
Out[429]: DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-03', '2018-01-05', 'NaT', 'NaT'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Thanks, Wen. You are right. Seems that I was not looking for shift index, but shift position. I believe that if now I want to shift n rows backward, I need to do something like: `Newindex= pd.Index([pd.NaT]* n )
Newindex= Newindex.append(index[: -n])`. Is that right?

Comment: @Saeed yeas, just change 1 to n